# Basic encryption using higher order functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a problem that runs along the lines of basic encryption. I'm trying to create a function called `encryptf` that

1. takes a list xs of a's
2. takes a list ys of a's
3. returns a function that maps elements of xs to the corresponding elements of ys and maps everything else to itself.

So far it looks like this:

```
encryptf :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> (a -> a)
encryptf xs ys = \f -> head [d | (c,d) <- (zip xs ys)]
```

Then there's a second function called `encryptString` that looks like this:

```
encryptString :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
encryptString f xs = map f xs
```

and these functions will be used like this:

```
encryptString (encryptf "abc" "xyz") "dcba"
```

and that would return `"dzyx"`

Now I know that my `encryptf` function is wrong, because it would change everything to the first element of ys. I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need  to look at your association list, `zip xs ys` and find the first element with a key (first element of the tuple) equal to `f` and return the value (second element of the tuple).  Using a `Map` will make it conceptually easier and operationally much faster.

Comment: Have a lookup at the [`lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) function.

Comment: You should consider using a Map data type for this job. Have a look at [`Data.Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is you search the given character in zipped list, and if it there then return second pair and if not then return the character itself.

```
encryptf :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> (a -> a)
encryptf xs ys = 
   let ret = zip xs ys in
   \f -> 
      case lookup f ret of
       Just c -> c
       Nothing -> f

encryptString :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
encryptString f xs = map f xs

*Main> encryptString (encryptf "abc" "xyz") "dcba"
"dzyx"
```